# Looping through a Vector

Tags: arrays, r, loops, vector, while-loop

I am using Rstudio and trying to create a function that will loop through a vector and perform a calculation with a while condition. The function should then return a data frame with the entered vector in one column and the number of iterations it took to satisfy the while condition in the another. 
I have already created a function that preformed the calculation with the while condition which serves as the basic operation for the function I am having problems with. Here it is:

```
t5<-function(x){
z=x
    while(x != 1){
        if(x %% 2 == 0)
            x= x/2
        else x= (3 * x +1)

        z=c(z, x)
}

return (z)
}
```

Here is what I have for the new function...my problem function (t7):

```
t7<-function(x){
 y=0
 i=0
 for(i in 1:length(x)){
 y[i]=length(t5(x[i]))-1
 print(y[i])

}
 #m<-data.frame(x, y[i])
}
```

I had it print y[i] because that is the only way the function does something. here is the output it shows (which is only half of what I need):

```
     t7(2:10)
     [1] 1
    [1] 7
    [1] 2
    [1] 5
    [1] 8
    [1] 16
    [1] 3
    [1] 19
    [1] 6
```

Can anybody help me understand how to make t7(2:10) run through this array and return a data frame listing the array and the number of iterations it took to reach the number 1 for each number in the array? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the vector you need with the `sapply` function:

```
data.frame(x=2:10, iters=sapply(2:10, function(x) length(t5(x))-1))
#    x iters
# 1  2     1
# 2  3     7
# 3  4     2
# 4  5     5
# 5  6     8
# 6  7    16
# 7  8     3
# 8  9    19
# 9 10     6
```

Comment: Or a modification is `data.frame(x=2:10, iters=lengths(sapply(2:10, t5))-1)`